# Conjugacy class of $\operatorname{Homeo}(\mathbb R)$.

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, continuity, normal-subgroups

$f_1(x)=2x$ and $f_2(x)=3x$ defines two homeomorphism from $\mathbb R$ to itself.
We have to show that $f_1,f_2$ belong to the same conjugacy class.

So,if $f_1,f_2$ belong to the same conjugacy class then $\exists g\in \operatorname{Homeo}(\mathbb R)$,such that $g \circ f_1 \circ g^{-1}=f_2$.

i.e. $g \circ f_1=f_2 \circ g$.

So,we have  to find $g$ such that $g(2x)=3g(x)$  $\forall x\in \mathbb R$.I am stuck at solving this functional equation.

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

If there is any other way to solve this problem without going into the functional equation, please feel free to write that down.

Also,I want to know about normal subgroups of $\operatorname{Homeo}(\mathbb R)$.If there is any good reference for that,please suggest in the comment section.

Comment: Hint: search for $g(x)=x|x|^{\alpha}$ where $\alpha$ is some positive real number.

Comment: Can you work out a simpler conjugacy, like between $f_1(x)=x+1$ and $f_2(x)=x+2$? It might give you some inspiration for how to do this one.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Yes,they are conjugate via $x\to 2x$.

Comment: @Mindlack Ahh!!That works.$\alpha$ turns to be $\frac{log 1.5}{log 2}$.I won't ask  how did you guess that.If  you could tell me some reference to study about normal subgroups and conjugacy classes of $Homeo(\mathbb R)$,it would be nice.

Comment: Exercise: a self-homeomorphism of $\mathbf{R}$ is conjugate to $x\mapsto 2x$ iff there exists $x_0\in\mathbf{R}$ such that $f(x)>x$ for all $x\ge x_0$ and $f(x)<x$ for all $x<x_0$.